# Visual Studio's Find window unusably small and not able to move

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Since several days my Visual Studio opens my Find window in a very unusable matter. All I see is a very large container but within it is just a small piece of the actual window, as wide as the "maximize" and "close" button. This means there is no title bar left to right click for a proper context menu, or to move the window to a place where I can dock it. All I can do is resize the outer container, not the actual content of the window.

Details:
Visual Studio 2010 with Resharper
Bugfix for growing Find-window installed

Already tried:
Remove all folders under "\Documents\Visual Studio 2010" except for the projects folder and start VS Again (didn't help).

Has anyone an idea of how I can solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Something tells me it has something to do with `Bugfix for growing Find-window installed`.

Comment: Try running Visual Studio in safe mode and see if that fixes your problem. (From the command prompt, execute: `devenv.exe /SafeMode`)